# Xamarin Forms label animation at bottom of screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm essentially making a 'shopping cart' UI and I want it so that when the user hits the 'Add' button, a little tiny box-label appears at the bottom of the screen that says 'Added Item' or something like that.

My question is how to do that with my current set up. I am currently using a nested Grid inside of a Scroll view for the main content of the page. I want the box-label to fade in at the bottom of the screen and stay located at the bottom of the screen ontop of everything else even if you scroll, until the animation fades.

Now i figure it doesn't make sense to add it into the grid since the grid's end will be out of view in the scrolling part of the scroll view, and same for the Scroll View. I am considering nesting the entire scroll view inside of a stack layout but i fear the button will just be located at the end of the stack layout under the scroll view instead of on TOP of the scroll view. How do you recommend I achieve this effect?

I prefer not to use a custom renderer if possible due to my lack of experience in the three separate platforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make vertically oriented stack layout. When you need to add you animation add it programmatically to the stack. When it finishes remove it from stack. Your scroll view will not affect animation

Comment: hey Yuri i have another quick question you might be able to help, if i wanted to accomplish the effect of having a box slide in from the side out of view, whats the easiest way to go about that? Do i just position it outside of the view and use translateTo to slide it in? or is it more than that? Thanks btw appreciated bud

Comment: I would start with translateTo. Just make sure you know where to start from :-) because screen can be rotated at this point

Comment: Appreciate your help. Can you give me a tip on positioning out of screen elements like that? I know i sound noobie but im still learning the Xamarin screen layout and manipulation, i come from a Unity background

Comment: I think application has static variables to store screen size (if not you can do it when app created). Then you can find out orientation and use width or height to set you beginning position before calling translate